# Необходимо, чтобы телеграмм бот сохранял изображение из сообщения пользователя, но не диске, а в оперативной памяти

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Ситуация такая, необходимо реализовать функцию бота так, чтобы когда пользователь отправлял боту сообщение с изображением, бот не скачивал это изображение на диск, а переводил его в оперативную память (в виде массива numpy мб) для дальнейшего анализа изображения нейросетью. У меня есть код, но он сохраняет изображение на моём жестком диске, но возможно ли изображение переводить в оперативную память без сохранения на диске?
Вот код на сохранение изображения на диске:
'''

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_photo(message):
    photo = message.photo[-1]
    file_info = bot.get_file(photo.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    filename = ''.join(choices(ascii_letters + digits, k=10)) + '.jpg'
    save_path = 'path_to_folder' + filename
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'The photo has been sent for processing! After the results, you can send another one!')'''
```

Comment: Попробуй использовать какое-нибудь key-value хранилище по типу redis, он как раз хранит информацию в ОП